# How to do horizontal drag and replace

Tags: angular, ng2-dragula, angular-dragula

**Use case description :**
I'm trying use drag and drop for a three columns to change their order (switch their position horizontally).
I tried the first example in the [demo page](https://valor-software.com/ng2-dragula/index.html) , but in my case i only want to drag horizontally, my markup look like the following :

```
<div class="horizontal segments" dragula="DRAGULA_FACTS">
<div class="column">content1</div>
<div class="column">content2</div>
<div class="column">content3</div>
</div>
```

It does relatively work, but only for dragging from right to left, and not in the opposite way (left to right).
Is there any way to achieve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, it's mentioned in [bavecqua/dragula](https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula#optionsdirection) , you should specify `direction` in the options, so I added this to my `home.component.ts` and changed the group name :

```
import {DragulaService} from 'ng2-dragula';

  constructor(private dragulaService: DragulaService) {
    dragulaService.createGroup("FEED", {
      direction:'horizontal'
    });
  }
```